# Sort columns by a specific criteria in R

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I want to sort some dataframes using a specific pattern criteria. I have some columns with prefix 'Saldo' and 'Concessões' both with suffix 'Real' and 'PIB'. I want to put them in the specific order: Saldo...PIB, Concessões...PIB, Saldo...Real, Concessões...Real.

Initial column names:

```
Saldo...PIB | Saldo...Real | Concessões...PIB | Concessões...Real
```

Desired output:

```
Saldo...PIB | Concessões...PIB | Saldo...Real | Concessões...Real
```

I've tried some combinations of select() and matches() but Im not so good at regular expressions.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can use regular expressions, you can also make use of `ends_with`, which might be easier. Here is a solution where `df` is your dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  select(ends_with("PIB"), ends_with("Real"))
```

Comment: It worked well! (I made only one modification to put '& matches(...)' to fit the whole dataframe). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your idea to use `select` was just fine!
I created some example data to illustrate my answer.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(SaldoReal = 1, SaldoPIB = 2, ConcessionsReal = 3, ConcessionsPIB = 4)

df %>% select(ends_with("PIB"), ends_with("Real"))
```

Results:

```
  SaldoPIB ConcessionsPIB SaldoReal ConcessionsReal
1        2              4         1               3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked well! (I made only one modification to put '& matches(...)' to fit the whole dataframe). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about my approach - really need to focus on RegEx in the future - and if it really fits your needs, but it seems to work with your example given.

```r
library(stringr)

# you can extract the column names of your df with `colnames()`
names <- c("Saldo...PIB", "Saldo...Real", "Concessões...PIB", "Concessões...Real")

ind_pib <- stringr::str_detect(names, pattern = "PIB")
ind_real <- stringr::str_detect(names, pattern = "Real")

c(names[ind_pib], names[ind_real])
#> [1] "Saldo...PIB"       "Concessões...PIB"  "Saldo...Real"     
#> [4] "Concessões...Real"
```